# Интерактивная таблица на Yii2 и AJAX

Tags: ajax, yii2

Пытаюсь сделать интерактивную таблицу в приложении на yii2, представляющую собой набор данных из бд, где при на нажатии на строку, меняется соответствующее поле с `true` на `false` и наоборот в соответствующем поле данных. Как всё это реализовать на простом php и ajax примерно представляю, но как это сделать красиво на yii2? Понятно что нужен обработчик в контроллере/действии и как-то запихать *ajax* в вид, но хотелось бы годный пример. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Официального сайта и документации вам мало?

Comment: Дайте ссылку на раздел мануала yii2 где описана работа с ajax и js скриптами. Все облазил, но ничего толкового не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Небольшой пример взаимодействия:

Некое действие:

```
public function actionSomeAjax(){
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    ....
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($answer);
}
```

Некое представление:

```
...
<?php
$this->registerJs('
    $(function(){
        $.get("/someController/some-ajax",function(data){
        ...
        })
    });
');
?>
```

То есть контроллер должен вернуть что либо (`return`), можно и просто `echo` в контроллере, но разработчики не рекомендуют. Так же можно вместо того что бы писать js код в представлении вынести его отдельно в файл и подключать, либо через [AssetBundle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html) либо опять же в представлении `$this->registerJsFile()`

Comment: ОК, спасибо за пример, более менее разобрался как подключать js в yii2, дальше дело техники.

Comment: Попробовал реализовать, всё получилось, только без JSON: при клике строка удаляется, а Ajax метод просто возвращает структуру и инфо новой строки через echo "<td>"; и т.д., и вставляется на его место.Подскажите, как правильно реализовать через JSON?

Comment: Вы описали удаление, по сути ничего возвращать не требуется кроме как статус удаления или ошибки. Если у вас там некое добавление, то можно html возвращать, тут пару моментов `return` в контроллере сработает так же как и `echo`, и второе, можно вынести формирования html из контроллера в представления и использовать `renderAjax`. Если хотите именно JSON, то отправлять все нужные данные массивом, а сам html составлять в javascript.